# Map 2 chunked arrays together by index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays i'd like to merge by index, the first looks like

```
[['$12.99', '$50.99'], ['$9.59', '$39.95'], ['..','..'], etc] // there are 2 strings in each chunk within the array

[['RBC', 'Term 20', '18%'], [..,..,..] etc] // there are 3 strings in each chunk
```

What I want to do is map the chunks together, so index 0 of each array will merge into their own array within the new array, and index 1 will do the same and so forth... What I would like in the end is a single array that looks like this...

```
[['RBC', 'Term 20', '18%', '$12.99', '$50.99'], [etc]]
```

I have tried a bunch of things, the closest I have is

`finalArrayForDisplay = tableDataDollarValue.map((e, i) => e + filteredTableArray2[i]);`

Which returns the following

```
[["$235.50,$21.19RBC ,Term 20 ,18.53%"]]
```

The array seems to be made up of 1 string, comma seperated.  Also, for whatever reason, there is no comma separation between the second and third elements.  Having lots of trouble here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your undesired result appears because `+` operator seems to convert your arrays to strings by default.

You're pretty close to the solution, but you should use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead, like this:

`finalArrayForDisplay = tableDataDollarValue.map((e, i) => e.concat(filteredTableArray2[i]));`

Answer (score 2):

To achieve expected result, use map with index

1. Use map to loop with value and index
2. Check if Array 2 value exits for that index
3. Concatenate both arrays based on index

```js
var arr1 =[['$12.99', '$50.99'], ['$9.59', '$39.95']] // there are 2 strings in each chunk within the array

var arr2 =[['RBC', 'Term 20', '18%']] // there are 3 strings in each chunk

console.log(arr1.map((v, i) => {
  if(arr2[i]){
  v = v.concat(arr2[i]);    
  }
  return v;
}))
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NWKdRrM?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like:

```js
tableDataDollarValue.map((arr, i) => arr.concat(filteredTableArray2[i]))
```

should do the trick, depending on what array is which.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and  [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
tableDataDollarValue.map((arr, i) => [...arr,...filteredTableArray2[i]])
```